# Entered fields not saving to model

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a pastebin clone in Django. I've created a paste app, and a Paste class in my `models.py`

```
class Paste(models.Model):
    SYNTAX_CHOICES = {
        (0, "Plain"),
        (1, "Python"),
        (2, "HTML"),
        (3, "SQL"),
        (4, "Javascript"),
        (5, "CSS"),
    }

    content     = models.TextField()
    title       = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    syntax      = models.IntegerField(choices=SYNTAX_CHOICES, default=0)
    poster      = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-timestamp',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.title or "#%s" % self.id,
            self.get_syntax_display())
    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail',
            None, {'object_id': self.id})

class PasteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'title', 'poster', 'syntax', 'timestamp')
    list_filter = ('timestamp', 'syntax')

admin.site.register(Paste, PasteAdmin)
```

In one of my templates, I have a form that requires the user enter the required details(name of paste, syntax, paste itself).

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Your user is</h1>
{{ request.user }}
{{ request.user.is.authenticated }}
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  Title:   <textarea rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="Title of paste"></textarea><br>
  Syntax:   <textarea rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="Enter syntax"></textarea><br>
  {{ form.content }}<br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Please enter the text you'd wish to paste..."></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Paste" id="submit">
{% endblock content %}
```

But when the information is entered, the data is not saved when checking the admin. What am I missing to save the entered information to that specific model?

As well, I have a registration form that creates new users, as well as a form that allows you to login/logout.

```
pastes/views.py

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

How would I go about linking the paste to the user? Or, allowing for it to remain anonymous?

Sorry for all the (dumb) questions, I'm quite lost in this and I've only been doing Django for 24 hours.

Comment: Note that `@permalink` has been obsolete for years - if it's in a book or tutorial, then I'd suggest looking for a different resource that is written for a modern version of Django.

Comment: Not sure why you posted the signup view but not the view that saves the pastebin data. Note though that your textareas don't have `name` attributes; the browser will just never send any data for them without those.

Comment: To expand on what Daniel said, the easiest way to get a view working at first is to use `{{ form }}` in the template. Once it's working, look at [working with form templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) if you want to customise the layout further.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, it's an outdated book. Is there an equivalent to that? Or should I just remove it from my code in it's entirety?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I guess that is the part that I am missing. How would I go about saving the pastebin data?

Comment: I don’t think the comments is the right place to fix that `get_absolute_url` method. My point is that you’ll find it easier to learn Django if you follow a recent guide, instead of learning out of date syntax then having to update it.